# Unity 2020.3.15f2 problem after updating Unity Ads is a video ad network for iOS and Android 4.0.1

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, ads

Here is where the problem is in my project:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public enum WatchAdResult { Finished, Failed, Skipped}
public class UnityAds : MonoBehaviour
{
    //delegate   ()
    public delegate void RewardedAdResult(WatchAdResult result);

    //event  
    public static event RewardedAdResult AdResult;

    public static UnityAds Instance;

    [Header("UNITY AD SETUP")]
    public string UNITY_ANDROID_ID = "1486550";
    public string UNITY_IOS_ID = "1486551";
    public bool isTestMode = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (UnityAds.Instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return; 
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        string gameId = "";
#if UNITY_IOS
        gameId = UNITY_IOS_ID;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        gameId = UNITY_ANDROID_ID;
#endif
        if (Advertisement.isSupported)
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, isTestMode);
        }
    }



    #region NORMAL AD
    public void ShowNormalAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
        }
    }

    public bool ForceShowNormalAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region REWARD AD
    public bool isRewardedAdReady()
    {
        return Advertisement.IsReady("rewardedVideo");
    }

    public void ShowRewardVideo()
    {
        ShowRewardedAd();
    }

    private void ShowRewardedAd()
    {
        if (!allowWatch)
            return;

        if (Advertisement.IsReady("rewardedVideo"))
        {
                var options = new ShowOptions { resultCallback = HandleShowResult };
                if (!Advertisement.isShowing)
                    Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo", options);

                allowWatch = false;
            
        }
    }

    bool allowWatch = true;
    private void HandleShowResult(ShowResult result)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case ShowResult.Finished:
                Debug.Log("The ad was successfully shown.");
                AdResult(WatchAdResult.Finished);
                ; break;
            case ShowResult.Skipped:
                Debug.Log("The ad was skipped before reaching the end.");
                AdResult(WatchAdResult.Skipped);
                break;
            case ShowResult.Failed:
                Debug.LogError("The ad failed to be shown.");
                AdResult(WatchAdResult.Failed);
                break;
        }

        allowWatch = true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Errors Encountered since updating:

1. UnityAds.cs(54,27): error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'IsReady'
2. UnityAds.cs(56,27): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Show' takes 0 arguments
3. UnityAds.cs(62,27): error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'IsReady'
4. UnityAds.cs(64,27): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Show' takes 0 arguments
5. UnityAds.cs(76,30): error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'IsReady'
6. UnityAds.cs(89,27): error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'IsReady'
7. UnityAds.cs(91,49): error CS0117: 'ShowOptions' does not contain a definition for 'resultCallback'

I would love to be able to update to the latest SDK for the "Advertisement Legacy" (4.4.2) in Unity but not sure if this will cause more problems than it would be worth

Everything was running fine until I updated from 3.7.5 to 4.0.1 because Google Play store removed my app and I've been trying to figure it out since.

Comment: You'll have to read some documentation and adjust your code. https://docs.unity.com/ads/en-us/manual/DeprecatedAPIClasses